# How to pass data from screen to screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

How i can pass data from one widget to another widget.
I'm getting data from firebase and I want the pass that data across the widget.
how I cant do it.

For example, for this, I'm getting data from this widget

```
class _SettingState extends State<Setting> {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    return StreamBuilder<UserData>(
        stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            UserData userData = snapshot.data;
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                 child: Text('working)
                )
               ]

            );
          } 
        });
  }
}
```

Now i want pass data to this widget

```
class Inbox extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InboxState createState() => _InboxState();
}

class _InboxState extends State<Inbox> {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: Text('Data'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the model class

```
class User {
  final String uid;

  User({this.uid});
}

class UserData {

  final String uid;
  final String username;
  final String phonenumber;


  UserData({ this.uid, this.username, this.phonenumber });
```

Comment: i think you need to checkout provider package for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a parameter to the `Inbox` widget, and use it in the state like this:

```dart
class Inbox extends StatefulWidget {
  final UserData userData;

  Inbox({Key key, this.userData}): super(key: key);

  @override
  _InboxState createState() => _InboxState();
}

class _InboxState extends State<Inbox> {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: Text(widget.userData.username),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send data to new screen using the parameters.

documentation for the same is [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data)

-----Screen where you have the data------

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: todos.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(todos[index].title),
      // When a user taps the ListTile, navigate to the DetailScreen.
      // Notice that you're not only creating a DetailScreen, you're
      // also passing the current todo to it.
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => DetailScreen(todo: todos[index]),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```

-----Screen where you need to pass the data------

```
class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  // Declare a field that holds the Todo.
  final Todo todo;

  // In the constructor, require a Todo.
  DetailScreen({Key key, @required this.todo}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Use the Todo to create the UI.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(todo.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Text(todo.description),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Happy Coding!!!